# PHP line length limits and arrays

Tags: php

Scenario:
I have a php file that I'm using by a zip code lookup form. It has number arrays of five digit zip codes running anywhere from 500 to 1400 zip codes. So far it works but I get PHP sniffer warnings in my code editor (Brackets) that I'm exceeding the 120 character limit.

Question:
Will this stop my PHP from running in certain browsers? 
Do I have to go to every 120 characters and do a return just to keep the line length in compliance?

It appears, I need to place these long strings into a database and call them in to the array rather than hang them all inside the PHP.

I am front-end designer so a lot to learn.

```
<?php

$zip = $_GET['zip']; //your form method is post

// Region 01 - PersonOne Name Zips 
$loc01 = array (59001,59002,59003,59004,59006);

// Region 02 - PersonTwo Name Zips 
$loc01 = array ("00001","00002","00003","00004","00006");

// Above numeric strings could include 2000 zips

// Region 01 - PersonTwo Name Zips
if (in_array($zip, $loc01)) {
header("Location: https://company.com/personone");

// Region 02 - PersonTwo Name Zips
if (in_array($zip, $loc02)) {
header("Location: https://company.com/persontwo");
```

Comment: Is there something you’re not telling us? Sniffer warnings from where?

Comment: I've never heard of a 120 character line length limit in HTML.

Comment: Can you post the exact warning from the sniffer?

Comment: The purpose of this limit is to make your code easier for other programmers to read, it has nothing to do with whether the script works.

Answer (score 2):

> Question: Will this stop my PHP from running in certain browsers?

No, PHP runs entirely on the server.  Browsers have nothing to do with PHP -- browsers are clients.  [Languages like HTML, CSS and (most) JavaScript are browser languages, but PHP is only server-side.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming)

> Do I have to go to every 120 characters and do a return just to keep the line length in compliance?

No, but I would highly suggest [using a database to store tons of records](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php) like this.  It's exactly what databases are for.  Alternatively you could put them in a file and simply read the file in with PHP's [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function.

Comment: I think what he really means in the first question is whether browsers will have trouble rendering what his PHP script sends.

Comment: He's getting the warning from a sniffer, so it must be talking about the data being sent between the server and client.

Comment: @Barmar, I think the OP is referencing a code style tool like [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer), not a network sniffer. The [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) standard has a "soft line length limit" of 120 characters.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. The name of the tool is poor, the usual name for things like this is "lint".

Comment: My coworkers have a bad habit of writing their SQL queries all on one line. I wish we adhered to a coding standard like this.

Comment: Yes, Barmar11, proper name is lint that is flagging the long, long arrays (ex: (65411,65412,65413,... ) for as many as 2,000 per group of zip codes.

Comment: Mr. Bing, I will see how I need to deposit these large arrays into a database for my on-demand retrieval. I'm a front-end designer so this is stretching my kluging skills. To make matters more confusing, zip codes preceded with zeros (ex. 09876 or 00654 are returning as 9876 or 654) are not matching. So, I will keep exploring.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to:

- Add each array into a mysql database record.
- Create a PHP script that fetches each array and applies it to the
  respective location.

This will eliminate the bloated lines of arrays numbers in PHP.
BTW, I also need to define these as 5 digit numeric strings as many of the zips start with one or two zeros which are ignored by the POST match.

Thanks everyone for the input.